# Laravel eloquent query on a relational table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am fairly new to laravel eloquent and i am trying to write a nested query to get data of food and food of resturent

I have two table one is `'food_list'` which mainly contain `'title','type'`
Type is int 0/1, 0 means veg and 1 means non veg
Another table i have `resturent _food`
Which has `restaurant_id, food_id,price, image`

Now i want to get food list of tge resturent which is only veg

So i wrote a query like this

```
RestaurantFood:with(['foodDetail'=>function($q){
$q->where('type',0);}])->where('id',$id)->get();
```

But this giving wrong answer

Can anyone please help me ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereHas()`:

```
RestaurantFood::with('foodDetail')->whereHas('foodDetail',function($q){
         $q->where('type',0);
})->where('id',$id)->get();
```