# Laravel 5.4: search by tag

Tags: php, laravel, search, controller, polymorphism

This works fine but what I want to know is if there is a better way to do a search for tags in Laravel. Thanks.

**Tag** model:

```
class Tag extends Model
{

    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Noticia', 'taggable');
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Noticia** model:

```
class Noticia extends Model
{

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'taggable');
    }

    // ...

}
```

**SearchController**

```
public function tag($id){

    $noticias= Noticia::all();
    $data['noticias'] = [];
    foreach($noticias as $value){
        foreach($value->tags as $tag){
            if($tag->id == $id){
                $data['noticias'][] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return view('web.buscar.index');
}
```

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860282/laravel-eloquent-query-on-a-relational-table/48860321#48860321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `whereHas()`

```
$noticias= Noticia::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id){
           $q->where('id',$id);
      })->get();
```

To get only `ids` use `pluck()`

```
$noticias= Noticia::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id){
           $q->where('id',$id);
      })->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel0415. And It´s possible to pick only the ids of the query without a foreach?

Comment: yes, it is possible, i am editing my answer for you :)

Comment: Oh! It´s true. I had forgotten ;) Thanks again.

Comment: we always do forget :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
public function tag($id){
   $noticicas = Noticia::has(['tags'=> function($query) use($id){
      return $query->where('id',$id);
   }])->get();
   dd($noticicas);

   //you can also, get the tag with the id you send, and then get all the `Noticias` for it
   $tag = Tag::find($id);
   $noticias = $tag->noticias->with(["tags"]); // the with is in case you want to show all the tags from the news
}
```