# how to use where in a query with Foreign key in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a query to get my data base on Dispenser's state_id. so here's my Database :

```
Dispenser Table: id, state_id, town_id, name.
Marketer Table: id, state_id, town_id, fname, lname.
DistributorDispenser Table: distributor_id['foreign key to distributor table', which it doesn't matter for this example], dispenser_id['foreign key to dispenser id'].
```

Consider below query which i was using for my spa which it's vue.js & laravel, now i want to change this query to check dispenser state_id then get detail base on user state_id.

I mean when we use relation to get some data base on relationship, like `->detail(function name in Model)`, i want my query to execute where query with `DistributorDispenser->dispenser->state_id` for my `auth()->user()->detail()->state_id`.

```
    return SellerCentralResources::collection(DistributorDispenser::where('state_id', auth()->user()->detail->state_id)
        ->latest()
        ->get());
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860282/laravel-eloquent-query-on-a-relational-table/48860321#48860321

Comment: @Sohel0415 worked man. if u can answer it, so i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
DistributorDispenser::query()
->whereHas('dispenser',function($q){
         $q->where('state_id', auth()->user()->detail->state_id);
})
->latest()
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've already solved it base on @Sohel0415's solution link. if he didn't answer it, i'll confirm your answer.